# What is the best way to enable several users to update the same database?

Tags: ms-access

I am currently on a mission and I'm facing a problem that I have never had to deal with before:

A classic Access 2003 database contains several tables that have to be updated by people located at different places in the company. What is the best way to enable different people to enter data in the tables ? Here are the few I have though of:

- the worse: each personn will modify the ONLY database file that will be sent to each people that want to update it
- the database is located on a server and people will connect to it, using forms to enter the data
- each time a person will have to enter data in the database, we will extract the table to Excel and then the person will modify it before it will be reimported to Excel

I guess (and hope) that the best solution is not among the three above, I need your advices, thank you !

Comment: Access was never meant to replace a true sql server.

Comment: On the same intranet but connected by ethernet (hundred kilometers away from each other)

Comment: That is going to be more difficult. You might like to read http://help.lockergnome.com/office2/Improving-performance-WAN--ftopict740608.html. Are these people doing much updating? Are there many people?

Comment: Some variation of option two I think is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is to split the database into front and back-ends. The front end is placed on each user's desktop and contains forms and reports. The tables are linked frrom the back-end, which is on a shared directory on your server.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167840(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: +1. Just to add, this works well as long as everyone has a relatively fast connection to the network. If you are going across a WAN or VPN, Access is not the best solution for either front or back end.

Comment: Also, a program like Tony Toews' [Auto FE Updater](http://autofeupdater.com/) is essential for updating the front-ends so you don't have to touch everyone's individual machines.

Answer (score 3):

If the users are in remote offices, use [Terminal Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068283/how-can-terminal-services-remote-desktop-be-used-to-share-an-access-database) that include the app file Remou suggested and link to the data file on a server the terminal service users have available. I don't know about Office licenses of having on user computer and the server.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple people need to edit the database concurrently, you should really be using a real Database server, such as SQL Server.

You can use Access as a front-end to SQL Server, so you won't need an additional interface.

Comment: The question implies a small number of users, which further suggests that SQL server would be overkill. There may not even be sufficient in-house expertise for such a solution. Also, i think you must mean SQL Server Express, or were you suggesting a very costly option?

Comment: Two users is enough to justify ditching Access for SQL Server Express ;)

Comment: @HardCode And you will volunteer maintenance for a company with two people? >:)